# Choosing data only if 25% quantile is higher than given value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame and i would like to get all data only if 25% percentile is over given value.

```
df['RaceRank'].describe()

count    5353.000000
mean      232.257713
std       347.250031
min         1.450000
25%        36.820000
50%        76.500000
75%       271.790000
max      1178.000000
Name: RaceRank, dtype: float64
```

I have tried following approach but didn't work for me:

```
d = df[df['RaceRank'].quantile(.25)>30]
```

And following one is not something i need i believe:

```
d = df[df['RaceRank']>df['RaceRank'].quantile(.25)]
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `get all data only if 25% is over given value`... maybe `if df['RaceRank'].quantile(.25) > 30: do_something_with_df`?

Comment: I'm trying to get dump them in a new DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do something like

```
mask = df['RaceRank'].quantile(.25) > 30
ones = np.ones(len(df), dtype=bool)

df[mask & ones]
```

Comment: describe shows me the 25% is 36.820000 but if i use this and select values below 38 for example, dataframe returns empty!

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted? Thats why I didn't understand the question.. you said `get all the data`, what do you mean by that?

Comment: I want to get rows if 25th quantile is lower than given value

Comment: The 25th percentile is a number.. In your example, it is `36.82`. This is constant, won't change (unless you change the initial data). So your sentence `"get rows if 25th quantile is lower than given value"` makes no sense !